# How to get the current TimeStamp?

Tags: qt, timestamp

I'm trying to get the current time as TimeStamp without success.

I have this code:

```
QDateTime setTime = QDateTime::fromString (QString("1970-07-18T14:15:09"), Qt::ISODate);
QDateTime current = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
uint msecs = setTime.time().msecsTo(current.time());

return  QString::number(msecs);
```

The output is

```
Sunday, January 25th 1970, 03:17:35 (GMT)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by timestamp? Please provide expected output.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you are looking for this function:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toTime_t

> uint QDateTime::toTime_t () const
>
> Returns the datetime as the number of seconds that have passed since 1970-01-01T00:00:00, > Coordinated Universal Time (Qt::UTC).
>
> On systems that do not support time zones, this function will behave as if local time were Qt::UTC.
>
> See also setTime_t().

Comment: i did that : QDateTime current = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
uint timestame = current.toTime_t(); ,but it didnt gave me the current date after i tested the result here : http://www.4webhelp.net/us/timestamp.php

Comment: just tried pass string returned by QDateTime::currentDateTime().toTime_t() to this site and got correct time. Maybe you set wrong timezone in the form on this site.

Comment: `toTime_t()` is deprecated, use `toSecsSinceEpoch()` instead (returns `qint64` instead of 32-bit `uint` that overflows in 2106 year)

Answer (score 94):

In Qt 4.7, there is the [`QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdatetime.html#currentMSecsSinceEpoch) static function, which does exactly what you need, without any intermediary steps. Hence I'd recommend that for projects using Qt 4.7 or newer.

Comment: Be aware that this returns the interval in **miliseconds** and not seconds. So it is not unix time!

Comment: Simply do (QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() / 1000) which should make it Unix time :P

Comment: This answer causes me to wasting time! because this is not exactly unix time as @martini mentioned.

Comment: In qt 5.8 (at the time of writing brand new) they have added the `currentSecsSinceEpoch` function: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#currentSecsSinceEpoch

Comment: Works on PyQt 5.10 which I believe uses Qt 5.10

Answer (score 11):

Since Qt 5.8, we now have [`QDateTime::currentSecsSinceEpoch()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#currentSecsSinceEpoch) to deliver the seconds directly, a.k.a. as real Unix timestamp. So, no need to divide the result by 1000 to get seconds anymore.

Credits: also posted as comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4460647). However, I think it is easier to find if it is a separate answer.